# Windows terminal displays "PS>" instead of the path

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, windows-terminal, oh-my-posh

I am setting up a new computer and can't get my oh-my-posh configuration working on my Powershell terminal. Powershell v7.4 is installed.

I have copied this across from my previous PC which is displaying correctly.

Profile ps1 (from `code $PROFILE`):

```
oh-my-posh --init --shell pwsh --config "C:\dropbox\oh-my-posh\themes\mytheme.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
$env:POSH_GIT_ENABLED = $true
```

Omp file:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/schema.json",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "alignment": "left",
      "segments": [
        {
          "background": "#1478DB",
          "foreground": "#000000",
          "leading_diamond": "\ue0b6",
          "trailing_diamond": "\uE0B0",
          "properties": {
            "style": "full"
          },
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": "{{ .Path }} ",
          "type": "path"
        },
        {
          "background": "#3AD900",
          "background_templates": [
            "{{ if or (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }}#FFC600{{ end }}",
            "{{ if and (gt .Ahead 0) (gt .Behind 0) }}#FFCC80{{ end }}",
            "{{ if gt .Ahead 0 }}#B388FF{{ end }}",
            "{{ if gt .Behind 0 }}#B388FF{{ end }}"
          ],
          "foreground": "#000000",
          "leading_diamond": "<transparent,background>\uE0B0</>",
          "trailing_diamond": "\ue0b4",
          "properties": {
            "fetch_stash_count": true,
            "fetch_status": true
          },
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": " {{ .HEAD }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }}<#FF6F00> \uf046 {{ .Staging.String }}</>{{ end }}{{ if and (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }} |{{ end }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uf044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .StashCount 0 }} \ueb4b {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }} ",
          "type": "git"
        }
      ],
      "type": "prompt"
    }
  ],
  "final_space": true,
  "version": 2
}
```

Display (working on PC #1):
[image]

Display (not working on new PC #2):
[image]

On the new PC I'm only seeing `PS>` and the command prompt.

If I run `oh-my-posh --init --shell pwsh --config "C:\dropbox\oh-my-posh\themes\cobalt2.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression` on the command line then the correctly formatted path appears for a short time, then reverts back to `PS>`. This tells me that oh-my-posh is correctly installed, and the omp file is also correctly configured.

All the other windows terminal settings from PC #1 have been backed up and copied across to PC # 2 too.

What other settings might I have missed to prevent the oh-my-posh path from being displayed?

---

#### UPDATE (debugging info)

Following the debugging information from @mklement0 below the following errors occurred:
[image]

Can anyone provide any information on these?

Comment: It looks like `Terminal-Icons` has not completely installed either. Some (but not all) of the icons are missing (pptx, xls, docx, md)

Comment: @mklement0 also, I've tried in both "Windows powershell" and the dotnet core "Powershell" - same issue in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- Generally, the **symptom implies that an unhandled terminating error (exception) occurs in the `prompt` function** (the function that prints the string at the start of each interactive prompt
  , causing PowerShell to fall back to its built-in default prompt string (`PS>`).
- The instructions below do *not* solve your problem, they help you **troubleshoot** it.

  - *Update*: You report that the problem turned out to be:
    "I was missing [posh-git](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-git) and the variable setting line `$env:POSH_GIT_ENABLED = $true` was failing."

---

###### Examining (the most) recent error(s):

As [Jan De Dobbeleer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5122929/jan-de-dobbeleer) points out, it may be sufficient to simply examine what error(s) occurred when the `prompt` function last executed, via the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), which records all errors that occur in a session:

- To start with a clean slate, clear the current value of `$Error`:

  ```bash
  $Error.Clear()
  ```
- After having submitted this command interactively, the `prompt` function immediately re-executes, and `$Error` will then contain any error(s) that it triggered.

To examine the *details* of the error(s) that occurred:

- If you're running [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), use the [`Get-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error) cmdlet:

  ```bash
  Get-Error # most recent error ($Error[0])

  $Error | Get-Error # ALL errors
  ```
- In *Windows PowerShell*, use the following instead (which produces less friendly output:

  ```bash
  $Error[0] | Format-List * -Force # most recent error ($Error[0])

  $Error | Format-List * -Force # ALL errors
  ```

Note:

- Since you're looking for a *terminating* (fatal) error, only `$Error[0]` should be of interest in your case.
- Generally, note that `$Error` also reflects *non-terminating* errors, including *silenced* ones (`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`), which therefore may *not* be indicative of an actual problem. (By contrast, `-ErrorAction Ignore` prevents recording in `$Error`.)
- Look for `ScriptStackTrace` in the output to see *where* the error occurred; in `Get-Error` output, `InvocationInfo` provides additional details.
- If that doesn't give you enough context, you can *debug* the function step by step to follow the flow of control, as explained next.

###### Debugging the `prompt` PowerShell function:

- Set a breakpoint for the `prompt` function so that the debugger is invoked every time the function executes:

  ```bash
  $bp = Set-PSBreakpoint -Command prompt
  ```

  - Use the following to remove it again later (or just start a new session):

    ```bash
     $bp | Remove-PSBreakpoint
    ```
- Given that you've just submitted a command, the `prompt` function is immediately invoked, and you can start debugging:

  - Once in the debugger, submit `?` to see a list of commands, `l` to list the function's source code; see the conceptual [about_Debuggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Debuggers) help topic for detailed guidance.
  - In the simplest case, submit `v` to skip from whole command to whole command, or `s` to step into a specific command, if possible. Just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> repeats the latest action (`v`, `s`, or `l`)
  - The source-code line containing the command about to be executed prints, with the command underlined with `~~~~~~~`.
  - Repeat `v` (or `s`) until the debugger unexpectedly exits: The last command executed was the one that caused the terminating error (exception).

Here's a screenshot demonstrating such a session:

[image: function-debugging screenshot]

- A dummy `prompt` function is defined that provokes a statement-terminating error (exception), with `1 / 0`
- A breakpoint is set for the function - by default at the start of the function, and having just submitted a command immediately invokes the `prompt` function and therefore enters the debugger.
- `v` is used to move from command to command, with the next command to execute underlined with `~~~~~~~~`
- Upon execution of `1 / 0`, the statement-terminating error that occurs both aborts the function execution and exits the debugger, pinpointing it as the offending command.
- If the offending command is itself a *PowerShell function or script*, you'll need to repeat the process and *step into* it during debugging, using `s` instead of `v`.
- Either way, `$Error` will reflect the error(s) that occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this was really useful for debugging. I have run that and you are correct that there are errors getting thrown, but once again I don't know what the cause is. I've added them to the question above for further information/.

Comment: The debug logs do not show the actual error. That should however always be inside the `$error` variable.

Comment: @JanDeDobbeleer D'oh! You're absolutely right - `$Error` should be the first thing that is consulted - I've added instructions to the answer.

Comment: @MarkCooper, please see the previous comments and the update to the answer re `$Error`. As for the original problem, assuming you still  want to debug: If the offending command is itself a *PowerShell function or script*, you'll need to repeat the process and _step into_ it during debugging, using `s` instead of `v`.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks both. This helped me work out that I was missing `posh-git` and the variable setting line `$env:POSH_GIT_ENABLED = $true` was failing.